# how to display model item on view

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

[image]i have a data which i Deserialize and its save in viewbag. [image]
here is the model jsonroot and then the formatted data in datalist model now i want to display the Property, oldValue on view how can i do this

i tried using this

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DataList)
    {
        @item.Property
    }
```

but it give error of
RuntimeBinderException: 'SmartAdmin.WebUI.Models.JsonRoot' does not contain a definition for 'Property'

Comment: What is your `ViewBag.DataList` value? Can you show how you initialize it in the controller? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun i had added it please check the edit

Comment: Kindly remind that to share your code as code snippet instead of images. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use Two `@foreach` to get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewBag.DataList` is a nested array.

You have to iterate the first level/root array and iterate the inner array which is `FormattedData` property.

```
@foreach (var jsonRoot in ViewBag.DataList)
{
    @foreach (var data in jsonRoot.FormattedData)
    {
        @data.Property
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this now i am getting this error
RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'SmartAdmin.WebUI.Models.JsonRoot' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Argh, sorry my mistake, should be: `jsonRoot.FormattedData`